# Gremlin using pipe output as an input again

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

I have a graph which looks like

```
a --father_of--> 1 --wife_of--> b --father_of-->2 --wife_of--> c --father_of--> 3--wife_of--> d --father_of --> 5--wife_of-->e
```

I want to write a query which gives me all fathers in the tree starting from a

I can get to one level by writing

`g.V('name','a').out(father_of).out(wife_of)`  which gives b

How can I write a recursive query giving b as input of the pipe so that the query gives me nodes b, c, d and e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the loop() and an emit-closure:

```
g.V('name','a').as('here').out('fatherOf').out('wifeOf').loop('here'){true}{true}
```